# Irregular responsive border for image?

Tags: html, css, border

So say I have a border like this:

[image: irregular border]

How would I go about making it responsive together with my image?

my initial idea was to have something like this:

```
<div class="frame">
            <img src="img/tourism.jpg" alt="image" class="bw-img">
            <img src="img/img-frame.png" alt="img frame" class="img-frame">
</div>
```

where I would basically absolutely position frame over my tourism image, both would have width 100% and matching initial size, but I'm not convinced its the way to go.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Place your border first then use position:absolute to stack it over the other image.

```
<div class="frame">
            <img src="img/img-frame.png" alt="img frame" class="img-frame"
                    style="position:absolute">
            <img src="img/tourism.jpg" alt="image" class="bw-img">

</div>
```

Edit: Just for info, z-index CSS property define which one will go on top. Highest value goes on top.

Answer (score 0):

Your frame is .png so you can make everything in it transparent, except for the border shapes. Next type the html you proposed above, and overlay your 2 images with css. Set the z-index of the frame image to a higher value than the z-index of the tourism.jpg. This should do the trick.